# Extracting only digits from a String

Tags: java, android

I have a Java String, i need to extract only the first digit from it.

for example the String:

> 2 fishes 3

I want to get only: "2" and this is my code:

```
String num1 = mEtfirst.getText().toString(); 
num1 = num1.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");
```

the code above accepts the two numbers which are 2 and 3 in "2 fishes 3" what i wish to achieve is to only accept or extract "2" and place it to num1. is it possible?

Comment: do you want only the first number?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code that you have written that isn't working?

Comment: @Christian welcome to StackOverflow, please post the code that you have tried :)

Comment: @Elenasys 
yes i only want to get the first number

Comment: @shoover
i have this line of codes:
String num1 = mEtfirst.getText().toString();
num1 = num1.replaceAll("[^0-9.,]+","");

the code above accepts the two numbers which are 2 and 3 in "2 fishes 3"
what i wish to achieve is to only accept or extrace "2".
is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Like sadegh points out, use **Regular expressions**:

```
String myString ="2 fishes 3"
myString = myString .replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

the result of `myString` is only the digits.

check the running example here:

http://ideone.com/Xg4xFc

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first numeric character you will use this snippet:

```
String myString = "2 fishes 3";
    if(myString.length()>0){ //to avoid index out of bounds!
        myString = myString.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        if(myString.length()>0){
            myString = String.valueOf(myString.charAt(0));
            System.out.println("myString : " + myString); //Numeric value found!
        }

    }
```

the result will be only the first numeric character: `2`

Comment: The above code will produce java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException if  myString = "fishes"; you need to put another if condition check on string length after you extract only digits from provided string.

Comment: uuups! yes you are right! I have updated the answer! =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with Regular expressions look at this

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm